# Observer is not called on LiveData change

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I have a list of dogs and when I tap on a particular dog from the list I can see the details. However, for some reason the textviews (dogName, dogPurpose, dogLifespan, etc.) are not udated. The detail fragment only displays the default values given by the XML layout. What could be the problem?

```
class DetailFragment : Fragment() {

    private var dogUuid = 0
    private lateinit var viewModel: DetailViewModel

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        arguments?.let {
            dogUuid = DetailFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it).dogUuid
        }

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DetailViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.fetch(dogUuid)

        observeViewModel()
    }

    private fun observeViewModel(){
        viewModel.dogLiveData.observe(this, Observer{ dog ->
            dog?.let {
                dogName.text = dog.dogBreed
                dogPurpose.text = dog.bredFor
                dogTemperament.text = dog.temperament
                dogLifespan.text = dog.lifeSpan
                context?.let {dogImage.loadImage(dog.imageUrl, getProgressDrawable(it))}
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This is the DetailViewModel.

```
class DetailViewModel(application: Application): BaseViewModel(application) {
    val dogLiveData = MutableLiveData<DogBreed>()

    fun fetch(uuid: Int){
        launch {
            val dog = DogDatabase(getApplication()).dogDao().getDog(uuid)
            dogLiveData.value = dog
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my implementation of the coroutines.

```
abstract class BaseViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application), CoroutineScope {

    private val job = Job()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

It seems the Observer inside the observeViewModel() is never called. Why?

Comment: Don't think it's cause of this issue but in general should use `viewLifecycleOwner` instead of `this` in call to `observe()`

Comment: I tried, but did not work.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `dogLiveData.value = dog` is being called?

Comment: fwiw I ran more or less same code here and it worked.

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly Could it be I screwed up something else? Perhaps coroutines? I will add my implementation of BaseViewModel.

Comment: That was one difference....I used `viewModelScope.launch` (using `ViewModel` built in `viewModelScope` ....available at least in relatively recent versions of libraries)

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly That might be it! But when I change the type to `DetailViewModel(): ViewModel()` I cannot call `val dog = DogDatabase(getApplication())` anymore since `getApplication()` is not available. What have you used instead?

Comment: Use `AndroidViewModel` instead of `ViewModel`

Comment: BTW why **onViewCreated()** why not **onActivityCreated()?** :/ i was wondering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I forgot to pass the argument `uuid` into `DetailFragment` which resulted in `dog` object being null in `DetailViewModel.fetch(uuid)`. Hence, the code above is correct and the problem was elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the line

```
dogLiveData.value = dog
```

is being called with a breakpoint?

Try calling

```
viewModel.fetch(dogUuid)
```

after

```
observeViewModel()
```

Comment: I have done that. Did not work, unfortunately. There seems to be no error in logs, I also tried cold boot and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Add `observeViewModel()` Befor  `viewModel.fetch(dogUuid)`

```
class DetailFragment : Fragment() {

    private var dogUuid = 0
    private lateinit var viewModel: DetailViewModel

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        arguments?.let {
            dogUuid = DetailFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it).dogUuid
        }

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DetailViewModel::class.java)

 observeViewModel()

 viewModel.fetch(dogUuid)


    }

    private fun observeViewModel(){
        viewModel.dogLiveData.observe(this, Observer{ dog ->
            dog?.let {
                dogName.text = dog.dogBreed
                dogPurpose.text = dog.bredFor
                dogTemperament.text = dog.temperament
                dogLifespan.text = dog.lifeSpan
                context?.let {dogImage.loadImage(dog.imageUrl, getProgressDrawable(it))}
            }
        })
    }
}
```